# How to clip children in qml?

Tags: google-maps, webview, qml

I have webView element that display google maps page. I need to show only map, without search input and other content. I have no idea except something like this:

```
Rectangle {
    x: 0
    y: 51
    height: 549
    //something like android clipChildren property

    WebView {
        id: mapView
        x:0
        y: -51
        width: 800
        height: 600
        url: ""
        onUrlChanged: {
            mapView.reload()
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know property that can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use the clip: true; property which is present on every item in QtQuick ?